# WildFly started with errors: java.net.BindException: Address already in use

Tags: eclipse, wildfly

When I start WildFly in Eclipse, I get this error:

```
22:03:42,430 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-2) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.serverManagement.controller.management.http: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.serverManagement.controller.management.http: WFLYSRV0083: Failed to start the http-interface service
    at org.jboss.as.server.mgmt.UndertowHttpManagementService.start(UndertowHttpManagementService.java:269)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
    at org.jboss.as.domain.http.server.ManagementHttpServer.start(ManagementHttpServer.java:160)
    at org.jboss.as.server.mgmt.UndertowHttpManagementService.start(UndertowHttpManagementService.java:235)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:437)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:429)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:67)
    at org.xnio.nio.NioXnioWorker.createTcpConnectionServer(NioXnioWorker.java:182)
    at org.xnio.XnioWorker.createStreamConnectionServer(XnioWorker.java:243)
    at org.jboss.as.domain.http.server.ManagementHttpServer.start(ManagementHttpServer.java:147)
    ... 6 more

22:03:42,431 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYJCA0001: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS]
22:03:42,551 INFO  [org.jboss.ws.common.management] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBWS022052: Starting JBoss Web Services - Stack CXF Server 5.0.0.Final
22:03:43,287 INFO  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 61) Mojarra 2.2.11-jbossorg-1 20150505-1501 für Kontext '/JSF Hello World' wird initialisiert.
22:03:43,721 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 61) WFLYUT0021: Registered web context: /JSF Hello World
22:03:43,727 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
    ("core-service" => "management"),
    ("management-interface" => "http-interface")
]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.serverManagement.controller.management.http" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.serverManagement.controller.management.http: WFLYSRV0083: Failed to start the http-interface service
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
    Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind"}}
22:03:43,758 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 34) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "JSF Hello World.war" (runtime-name : "JSF Hello World.war")
22:03:43,786 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0183: Service status report
WFLYCTL0186:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.serverManagement.controller.management.http: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.serverManagement.controller.management.http: WFLYSRV0083: Failed to start the http-interface service

22:03:43,884 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0063: Http management interface is not enabled
22:03:43,884 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0054: Admin console is not enabled
22:03:43,884 ERROR [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0026: WildFly Full 9.0.1.Final (WildFly Core 1.0.1.Final) started (with errors) in 12675ms - Started 270 of 455 services (2 services failed or missing dependencies, 221 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)
```

How can I resolve this problem?

There are some connections on port 80. Do I have to check all ip adresses with whois to identify an application on my computer which is already using port 80?

```
C:\Users\me7D-User>netstat -aon | findstr "80"
  TCP    0.0.0.0:8092           0.0.0.0:0              ABHÖREN         4
  TCP    127.0.0.1:8080         0.0.0.0:0              ABHÖREN         8868
  TCP    127.0.0.1:8080         127.0.0.1:59241        HERGESTELLT     8868
  TCP    127.0.0.1:59177        127.0.0.1:8080         WARTEND         0
  TCP    127.0.0.1:59180        127.0.0.1:59181        HERGESTELLT     8868
  TCP    127.0.0.1:59181        127.0.0.1:59180        HERGESTELLT     8868
  TCP    127.0.0.1:59230        127.0.0.1:8080         WARTEND         0
  TCP    127.0.0.1:59241        127.0.0.1:8080         HERGESTELLT     11024
  TCP    192.168.0.100:59166    173.194.113.41:80      WARTEND         0
  TCP    192.168.0.100:59249    104.16.102.85:80       HERGESTELLT     8392
  TCP    192.168.0.100:59250    216.58.211.42:80       HERGESTELLT     8392
  TCP    192.168.0.100:59252    103.31.7.34:80         HERGESTELLT     8392
  TCP    192.168.0.100:59253    216.58.211.42:80       WARTEND         0
  TCP    192.168.0.100:59254    190.93.247.58:80       HERGESTELLT     8392
  TCP    192.168.0.100:59255    190.93.247.58:80       HERGESTELLT     8392
  TCP    192.168.0.100:59256    190.93.247.58:80       WARTEND         0
  TCP    192.168.0.100:59257    190.93.247.58:80       HERGESTELLT     8392
  TCP    192.168.0.100:59258    190.93.247.58:80       HERGESTELLT     8392
  TCP    192.168.0.100:59259    190.93.247.58:80       HERGESTELLT     8392
  TCP    192.168.0.100:59264    104.16.12.8:80         HERGESTELLT     8392
  TCP    192.168.0.100:59265    88.221.92.32:80        HERGESTELLT     8392
  TCP    192.168.0.100:59266    88.221.92.176:80       HERGESTELLT     8392
  TCP    192.168.0.100:59267    173.194.113.36:80      HERGESTELLT     8392
  TCP    192.168.0.100:59268    104.16.12.8:80         WARTEND         0
  TCP    192.168.0.100:59269    88.221.92.32:80        WARTEND         0
  TCP    192.168.0.100:59270    88.221.92.176:80       WARTEND         0
  TCP    192.168.0.100:59271    54.204.10.55:80        HERGESTELLT     8392
  TCP    192.168.0.100:59272    54.204.10.55:80        WARTEND         0
  TCP    192.168.0.100:59273    95.172.94.34:80        WARTEND         0
  TCP    192.168.0.100:63749    216.34.181.97:80       SCHLIESSEN_WARTEN    1680

  TCP    192.168.0.100:63812    216.34.181.97:80       SCHLIESSEN_WARTEN    1680

  TCP    [::]:8092              [::]:0                 ABHÖREN         4
  UDP    127.0.0.1:49880        *:*                                    3272
  UDP    [fe80::100:7f:fffe%11]:54045  *:*                                    49
56
  UDP    [fe80::5efe:192.168.0.100%15]:54045  *:*
     4956
  UDP    [fe80::5efe:192.168.137.1%14]:54045  *:*
     4956
  UDP    [fe80::a9:d477:68a9:2472%10]:1900  *:*
   3364
  UDP    [fe80::a9:d477:68a9:2472%10]:54045  *:*
    4956
  UDP    [fe80::a9:d477:68a9:2472%10]:56718  *:*
    3364
  UDP    [fe80::3d9d:1f6f:e25:35b%13]:53  *:*
 1292
  UDP    [fe80::3d9d:1f6f:e25:35b%13]:546  *:*
  1100
  UDP    [fe80::3d9d:1f6f:e25:35b%13]:1900  *:*
   3364
  UDP    [fe80::3d9d:1f6f:e25:35b%13]:54045  *:*
    4956
  UDP    [fe80::3d9d:1f6f:e25:35b%13]:56719  *:*
    3364
```

And these are on port 8080.

```
C:\Users\me7D-User>netstat -aon | findstr "8080"
  TCP    127.0.0.1:8080         0.0.0.0:0              ABHÖREN         7500
  TCP    127.0.0.1:8080         127.0.0.1:60095        HERGESTELLT     7500
  TCP    127.0.0.1:8080         127.0.0.1:60096        HERGESTELLT     7500
  TCP    127.0.0.1:60035        127.0.0.1:8080         WARTEND         0
  TCP    127.0.0.1:60095        127.0.0.1:8080         HERGESTELLT     11024
  TCP    127.0.0.1:60096        127.0.0.1:8080         HERGESTELLT     11024
```

This error is always present, also if I restart my computer.

Comment: Visiting localhost:8080 says:"Your WildFly 9 is running."

Comment: So, you have two? Or, you manually installed WildFly as a Windows Service too?

Comment: No. I just added WildFly as server in Eclipse on Windows. I unpacked the rar file into C before:.

Answer (score 59):

Check if you have service called **NVIDIA Network Service** running at your computer.

Coincidentally this **NVIDIA Service** is running at the **port 9990**, used for the **Admin console of Wildfly**.

[image: Windows Services]

In my case, it was only stop this Service and restart the Wildfly server.

Comment: This worked and I have window 10 NVIDIA 950M as a graphic card. http://localhost:9990/console/App.htm

Comment: I would like to know how NVidia decide for such port. It is the most common  used port, especially if you're a developer (like me). I would like to reassign...maybe there's a config for nvidia service....

Comment: Hi Mark, good question, I do not know why to use such a so common used port! So, yes I do... I am developer as you too, but... actually I did not investigate any configuration at NVIDIA (files) to check if it is possible to modify this port.

Answer (score 6):

WildFly is trying to use a port in your PC is already in use. Check in your logs for: “**Caused by: java.net.BindException**: **Address already in use: bind**”

Check the port WildFly is using and then you can check if this port is being use for any other application, it could be another instance of WildFly but can be any other application too. For example the port **80** could be apache/IIS or any other web server running in your PC.

Normally WildFly (and JBOSS) use **8080** by default and looks like you have an application listen in this port, also WildFly use few more ports for other protocols and management that the app server needs. Using the command netstat you can check what other app is using those ports, for example (for 8080 port) you can use the command:

**netstat -aon | findstr :8080**

If you want to do a quick test you can pass this parameter to WildFly “**-Djboss.socket.binding.port-offset=2000**” this will increase all the ports JBOSS/WildFly use by 2000 (or any other value), then for example if your WildFly was running in "**localhost:8080/your-context**" now will be "**localhost:10080/your-context**".

If your JBOSS/WildFly is running in port **80** you can play with this parameter to test with another port too, for example “**-Djboss.socket.binding.port-offset=10000**” will bring you also with  the port **10080**.

Good luck ;)

Comment: There are no connections untill I start wildfly from eclipse. Then I can see three connections. Two of them left when I stop wildfly.

Answer (score 2):

This port already used by NVIDIA  or another process. Another way to resolve this problem is to changing default admin port.

To change the port you have to modify standalone.xml which is resides inside `standalone\configuration` folder. Find the port `9990`. Now change the offset from 0 to 1  `jboss.socket.binding.port-offset:1`

it will increase default port value from `9990` to `9991`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Wildfly is already running when you try to start it. Check your process viewer, it may show up as wildfly it may show up just as 'java'.

You could be running it as a service, you could be running it from the command line, it is possible that Eclipse started it and isn't aware of it any longer.

Comment: JBoss is running if I start Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Just checking my (default) port in a browser via **http://localhost:8080** it was obvious it was a service/application I installed/tested called **Intrexx** (which btw. uses the Tomcat application server).
After deinstallation everything was fine again.