# WildFly - Cannot access to admin console (404 Error code)

Tags: java, eclipse, jboss, eclipse-neon

First thing, I already saw posts on it on Stackoverflow 
(like this : [Wildfly 9.x startet with errors: Address already in use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32017970/wildfly-9-x-startet-with-errors-address-already-in-use)) but no solution is working (changing the port , check if another server is running , etc) and got Jboss in a zip from http://tools.jboss.org/downloads/jbosstools/neon/4.4.0.Final.html#zips (because my eclipse marketplace didn't find it)

Bad luck this time when I start my WildFly Server on Eclipse :

```
23:47:12,788 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] (main) JBoss Modules version 1.5.1.Final
23:47:15,449 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] (main) JBoss MSC version 1.2.6.Final
23:47:15,530 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYSRV0049: WildFly Full 10.0.0.Final (WildFly Core 2.0.10.Final) starting
23:47:25,711 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0039: Creating http management service using socket-binding (management-http)
23:47:26,198 INFO  [org.xnio] (MSC service thread 1-6) XNIO version 3.3.4.Final
23:47:26,376 INFO  [org.xnio.nio] (MSC service thread 1-6) XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.3.4.Final
23:47:26,637 WARN  [org.jboss.as.txn] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 54) WFLYTX0013: Node identifier property is set to the default value. Please make sure it is unique.
23:47:26,654 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.io] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 37) WFLYIO001: Worker 'default' has auto-configured to 8 core threads with 64 task threads based on your 4 available processors
23:47:26,658 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jsf] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 44) WFLYJSF0007: Activated the following JSF Implementations: [main]
23:47:26,945 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 53) WFLYSEC0002: Activating Security Subsystem
23:47:26,978 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 38) WFLYCLINF0001: Activating Infinispan subsystem.
23:47:27,100 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYSEC0001: Current PicketBox version=4.9.4.Final
23:47:27,134 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYJCA0009: Starting JCA Subsystem (WildFly/IronJacamar 1.3.2.Final)
23:47:27,433 INFO  [org.jboss.as.webservices] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 56) WFLYWS0002: Activating WebServices Extension
23:47:27,692 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 46) WFLYNAM0001: Activating Naming Subsystem
23:47:27,704 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 55) WFLYUT0003: Undertow 1.3.15.Final starting
23:47:27,705 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYUT0003: Undertow 1.3.15.Final starting
23:47:29,761 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 33) WFLYJCA0004: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class org.h2.Driver (version 1.3)
23:47:29,764 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYJCA0018: Started Driver service with driver-name = h2
23:47:30,400 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 55) WFLYUT0014: Creating file handler for path 'C:\Progs\wildfly-10.0.0.Final/welcome-content' with options [directory-listing: 'false', follow-symlink: 'false', case-sensitive: 'true', safe-symlink-paths: '[]']
23:47:31,056 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYNAM0003: Starting Naming Service
23:47:31,057 INFO  [org.jboss.as.mail.extension] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYMAIL0001: Bound mail session [java:jboss/mail/Default]
23:47:32,848 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYEJB0482: Strict pool mdb-strict-max-pool is using a max instance size of 16 (per class), which is derived from the number of CPUs on this host.
23:47:32,848 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYEJB0481: Strict pool slsb-strict-max-pool is using a max instance size of 64 (per class), which is derived from thread worker pool sizing.
23:47:32,978 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYUT0012: Started server default-server.
23:47:32,980 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYUT0018: Host default-host starting
23:47:33,057 INFO  [org.jboss.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBoss Remoting version 4.0.18.Final
23:47:33,824 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYUT0006: Undertow HTTP listener default listening on 0.0.0.0:8080
23:47:34,863 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYJCA0001: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS]
23:47:35,357 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYDS0013: Started FileSystemDeploymentService for directory C:\Progs\wildfly-10.0.0.Final\standalone\deployments
23:47:35,421 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "postgresql-9.3-1103.jdbc4.jar" (runtime-name: "postgresql-9.3-1103.jdbc4.jar")
23:47:37,241 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-5) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.serverManagement.controller.management.http: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.serverManagement.controller.management.http: WFLYSRV0083: Failed to start the http-interface service
    at org.jboss.as.server.mgmt.UndertowHttpManagementService.start(UndertowHttpManagementService.java:271)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
    at org.jboss.as.domain.http.server.ManagementHttpServer.start(ManagementHttpServer.java:157)
    at org.jboss.as.server.mgmt.UndertowHttpManagementService.start(UndertowHttpManagementService.java:237)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(Unknown Source)
    at org.xnio.nio.NioXnioWorker.createTcpConnectionServer(NioXnioWorker.java:192)
    at org.xnio.XnioWorker.createStreamConnectionServer(XnioWorker.java:243)
    at org.jboss.as.domain.http.server.ManagementHttpServer.start(ManagementHttpServer.java:144)
    ... 6 more

23:47:37,300 INFO  [org.infinispan.factories.GlobalComponentRegistry] (MSC service thread 1-1) ISPN000128: Infinispan version: Infinispan 'Mahou' 8.1.0.Final
23:47:37,300 INFO  [org.infinispan.factories.GlobalComponentRegistry] (MSC service thread 1-7) ISPN000128: Infinispan version: Infinispan 'Mahou' 8.1.0.Final
23:47:37,301 INFO  [org.infinispan.factories.GlobalComponentRegistry] (MSC service thread 1-8) ISPN000128: Infinispan version: Infinispan 'Mahou' 8.1.0.Final
23:47:42,235 INFO  [org.jboss.ws.common.management] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBWS022052: Starting JBossWS 5.1.3.Final (Apache CXF 3.1.4) 
23:47:44,552 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYJCA0005: Deploying non-JDBC-compliant driver class org.postgresql.Driver (version 9.3)
23:47:44,707 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYJCA0018: Started Driver service with driver-name = postgresql-9.3-1103.jdbc4.jar
23:47:45,394 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
    ("core-service" => "management"),
    ("management-interface" => "http-interface")
]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.serverManagement.controller.management.http" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.serverManagement.controller.management.http: WFLYSRV0083: Failed to start the http-interface service
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
    Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind"}}
23:47:45,588 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 34) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "postgresql-9.3-1103.jdbc4.jar" (runtime-name : "postgresql-9.3-1103.jdbc4.jar")
23:47:45,589 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0183: Service status report
WFLYCTL0186:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.serverManagement.controller.management.http: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.serverManagement.controller.management.http: WFLYSRV0083: Failed to start the http-interface service

23:47:45,967 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0063: Http management interface is not enabled
23:47:45,967 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0054: Admin console is not enabled
23:47:45,968 ERROR [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0026: WildFly Full 10.0.0.Final (WildFly Core 2.0.10.Final) started (with errors) in 34185ms - Started 307 of 603 services (2 services failed or missing dependencies, 379 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)
```

What I understood with these lines is that this address is already in use.

I start this cmd command before and after the start of the server :

> netstat -aon | findstr :8080

Before :
[image: Before running server]

After :
[image: After trying to run server]

I can access on the default page (localhost:8080) :
[image: Default page]

When I click on "Administration Console" , I got this :
[image: 404 page]

Any solution ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally , I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35374414/6149867) (Thanks Ualter Jr.) :

> Check if you have service called NVIDIA Network Service running at your computer. Coincidentally this NVIDIA Service is running at the port 9990, used for the Admin console of Wildfly. In my case, it was only stop this Service and restart the Wildfly server.

[image: Nvidia Network Service]